# Set background div as content for foreground div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying a design where there are three divs as shown in image. Div1 and 2 are of same size and are on top of each other. They each have an image as background. Now Div3 smaller and initially at bottom left, will move from bottom left to top right. As it moves, I want the image in Div1 to show. I dont want Div1 image to fit entirety of div3. But for the size of div3, the image in div1 must show and div2 must hide.

I am not able to use hover for this. As hover changes the image completely. How do I achieve this?[[image: image describing layout]]

Comment: Use animations. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: Could you put up a runnable snippet - it makes it much easier to give a solution if we can see your HTML structure. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this. What I understand you need is for the bit of div2 which div3 is over to seem to become transparent, so that bit of div1 can be seen. Can you confirm that I have understood correctly?

Comment: @AHaworth yes. you are right.